# ios swift uitabbar replace view controllers crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am really struggling with what should be a simple bit of code.

I have an ios app that has 4 tabs in the uitabcontroller, depending on the a setting in another tab I wanted to replace the controller the first tab goes to.  I found that I couldnt simply replace this first tab (although i managed it somehow for a couple of builds then it stopped working after a clean).

So I went for the option of replacing the viewcontrollers that the tab controller references with the .setViewControllers method.  I call this from my viewcontroller after the viewdidload method.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc0 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("collection")
let vc4 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profilenews1")

let vc1: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("news") as UIViewController
let vc2: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("create") as UIViewController
let vc3: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("search") as UIViewController

let controllers = [vc0,vc4]
self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
```

From the research I have done this should work, setViewControllers is documented and I have seen numerous objective c examples but I get EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION thrown.

I have checked that the tabcontroller is correct before I replace by doing

```
println("number of navs: \(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.count)")
```

And that prints the correct number of controllers.

Any ideas?

Comment: What line throws the exception? Also, why are you creating vc1, vc2, and vc3 and then not doing anything with them?

Comment: Does that code even compile? You should have "as UIViewController" at the end of your lines that create vc0 and vc4.

Comment: code does compile and I had as UIViewControllers on there before.

Comment: I cut down the number of tabs for testing which is why VC1, VC2 and VC3 are not added to the controllers array

Comment: The line that throws the exception is the self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers

Comment: Hi, @user2230198 I am also getting crash. Did you solve this?